# Sliding an image with fixed header and footer in WP7

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to implement slide transition on an image on a page where header and footer on the same page remain fixed while sliding? for example a set of images are to flicked with slide transition and doing this has not effect on the header and footer on the same pages.

I did try searching on net but all I came across was Page transition and not any item or field Transition.

Any help would be great :)

EDIT:
I tried some UIElement transition using ITransition interface but sliding gives Fading also with it.I s it possible to remove fading and just show sliding in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use element transition something like:

```
    SlideTransition slideTransition = new SlideTransition();
    ITransition transition = slideTransition.GetTransition(TargetImage);
    transition.Completed += delegate
    {
        transition.Stop();
    };
    transition.Begin();
```

GetTransition(UIElement element) creates a new ITransition for the specified UIElement.

note:Handling of the Completed event is optional and it depends on the specified animation.

Comment: I did try using..it worked fine.But it gives a fade in  transition also along with slide.I went through the SlideTransition class and it contains definitons for modes like : SLideLeftInFadeOut,SlideLeftOutFadeIn and so on.But i dont want the fading.Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: Yes you can implement a custom transition. Just grab the code from the toolkit and modify it to remove the fade effect.

Comment: I am a novice in all this ..so can u just provide a little code help on how to do this?